# How can I use wired ethernet + external monitor together on my Macbook Air (Late 2013)?

Tags: network, macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt

I have a late 2013 MBA which only has USB 3 ports and one Thunderbolt port. I've currently been using a Thunderbolt to Ethernet adapter to use wired internet, but I'd also like to use an external monitor at the same time. Are there any USB to HDMI or USB to Ethernet (provided that the internet speed won't be decreased) adapters which I could use?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Apple sells an [USB Ethernet adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC704ZM/A/apple-usb-ethernet-adapter?fnode=51). But since it's USB 2 it's likely to speed down the network capabilities.

There are [other adapters](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A0ABQLM) with USB3 which seems to be faster (and compatible with OSX) .

Comment: In my experience, non Apple-branded ethernet <> USB adaptors just don't work at all, or work poorly, unless specifically designated as OS X compatible. In general, I've found the Apple adaptors to be more physically robust and less prone to self-disassembly. In any case, unless you really need gigabit network speeds, the Apple USB2 <> 10/100Mbt adaptor works just fine - I've been using mine for years. It does get warm with use, though, so it's eating some battery life you wouldn't otherwise suspect.

Comment: there are also usb3-gigabit adapters with built-in usb hub, compatible with mac as this: http://amzn.to/1lPPczu